# Pandas: Rolling sum with multiple levels of grouping

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to obtain rolling sum on a data frame after multiple levels of grouping:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
year_vec = np.arange(2000, 2005)
month_vec = np.arange(1, 4)
soln_list = []
firmList = [61, 62, 63]
firmId = []
year_month = []
year = []
month = []
for firmIndex in range(0, len(firmList)):
    for yearIndex in range(0, len(year_vec)):
        for monthIndex in range(0, len(month_vec)):
            soln_list.append("soln_%s_%s_%s" % (firmList[firmIndex], year_vec[yearIndex], month_vec[monthIndex]))
            firmId.append(firmList[firmIndex])
            month.append(month_vec[monthIndex])
            year.append(year_vec[yearIndex])
            year_month.append("%s_%s" % (year_vec[yearIndex], month_vec[monthIndex]))

df = pd.DataFrame({'firmId': firmId, 'year': year, 'month': month, 'year_month' : year_month,
                   'soln_vars': soln_list})
df = df.set_index(["firmId", "year_month"])
```

The resulting data frame looks as follows:

```
                      month       soln_vars  year
firmId year_month                             
61     2000_1          1  soln_61_2000_1  2000
       2000_2          2  soln_61_2000_2  2000
       2000_3          3  soln_61_2000_3  2000
       2001_1          1  soln_61_2001_1  2001
       2001_2          2  soln_61_2001_2  2001
       2001_3          3  soln_61_2001_3  2001
       2002_1          1  soln_61_2002_1  2002
        ...                   ...         ...
```

At this point I want a rolling sum of `soln_vars` over every 2 years, over every month for each firm. To do so, I first group by `firmId` and `year` and then sum:

```
  df = df.groupby([df.index.get_level_values(0), "year"])["soln_vars"].sum()
```

This operation gives me the sum of `soln_vars` over every year for each firm:

```
firmId  year
61      2000    soln_61_2000_1soln_61_2000_2soln_61_2000_3
        2001    soln_61_2001_1soln_61_2001_2soln_61_2001_3
        2002    soln_61_2002_1soln_61_2002_2soln_61_2002_3
        2003    soln_61_2003_1soln_61_2003_2soln_61_2003_3
        2004    soln_61_2004_1soln_61_2004_2soln_61_2004_3
62      2000    soln_62_2000_1soln_62_2000_2soln_62_2000_3
        2001    soln_62_2001_1soln_62_2001_2soln_62_2001_3
        ...                    ...
```

In my application the solution variables are provided by another library that result in mathematical expressions: `soln_61_2000_1 +soln_61_2000_2 
+ soln_61_2000_3` - I am using strings here for simplicity.
Then grouping by `firmId` and applying rolling sum:

```
  df = df.groupby(level=0, group_keys=False).rolling(2).sum()
```

does not change `df`. Any help is appreciated in clarifying this.